# Как понять какой view был обновлен?

Tags: android

Eсть `scrollview`, внутри `Linearlayout`, а внутри `Linearlayout` динамически создаются(добавляются) `view` разного типа(`edittext, spinner, date...`) и заполняются данными, у всех `enable(false)`.

Нажимаем edit, меняем например инфу одного из edittext и date.
Вопрос, как правильно определить, инфо какой именно view был обновлен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать двойной databinging. Тогда данные, которые устаналиваюся во View-их, по завершении экрана будут стянуты в объекты. А объеты уже можно сравнить. Попробуйте вот эту статью https://habr.com/post/260317/ по обратной свяи.